# Is there a way to apply multiple Array methods to an array in 1 line?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the simple test code below I `push` the number 10 into an array and then `splice` 'hello world' into the array on the 2nd index.  It works as expected.

```js
"use strict";

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

myArray.push(10);
myArray.splice(2, 0, 'hello world');

console.log(myArray);
```

However is it possible to do this on one line?  I tried chaining in the example below and it throws an error.  I can't find anyone talking about this online.

```js
"use strict";

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

myArray.push(10).splice(2, 0, 'hello world');

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: `push()` returns the new length of the array, not the array itself, so you can't chain it.

Comment: You can override the methods on Array.prototype, but you can't change the return value of `push` and `splice` (which would have to be the array)

Comment: As @Francesco alludes to in their answer, what is the benefit of doing this in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a modern JavaScript browser the `push` part is a little easier, using the [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Since everyone else is using chaining (which requires altering the built-in Array object, which I don't like), I'll use something different:

```js
"use strict";

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function notSplice(array, start, end, ...items) {
  array.splice.apply(array, [start, end, ...items]);
  return array;
}

myArray = notSplice([...myArray, 10], 2, 0, 'hello world');

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: To be clear, this does not perform the operation in one line: it does in in 5 lines, since `notSplice` takes 4. I agree wholeheartedly with the point [Franceso makes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50728486).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to do it in one line.

```js
"use strict";

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

myArray.push(10); myArray.splice(2, 0, 'hello world');

console.log(myArray);
```

But why do you want to do that in one line? If your concern is readability I would stick with two lines. If you want it more functional, then use a functional library

**edit**

I agree with what every one else said about chainability. I'm just trying to make another point

Comment: I like your thinking :)

Answer (score 3):

These built-in methods are not designed to be part of a fluent interface, as they don't return the array that they're operating on (`push()` returns the new length, `splice()` returns the sub-array that was removed). You could add your own methods that are similar but are fluent.

```js
Array.prototype.mypush = function(...args) {
  this.push(...args);
  return this;
};
Array.prototype.mysplice = function(...args) {
  this.splice(...args);
  return this;
}

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

myArray.mypush(10).mysplice(2, 0, 'hello world');

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the methods and parameters in an array and iterate with a function, which take the array as `this` value.

```js
"use strict";

function arrayFn([k, ...a]) { this[k](...a); }

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

[
    ['push', 10],
    ['splice', 2, 0, 'hello world']
].forEach(arrayFn, myArray);

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Hi Nina, I selected a different answer because it was somewhat simpler.  However I'm going to deconstruct your brilliant code. I didn't realize I could use an array to store the strings 'push' and 'splice' and pass/use them like that.  Wow!

Comment: I like that this answer "thinks outside the box", even if it's a little hard to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Chaining works by calling a method of the return value of the previous method call. For example:

```
myArray.filter(...).map(...).join(', ').trim()

// is equivalent to

const filteredArray = filtered.map(...)    
const mappedArray = filteredArray.map(...) // filteredArray is an array, we can use map.
const aString = mappedArray.join(', ')     // mappedArray is an array, we can use join
const trimmedString = aString.trim()       // aString is a string, we can use trim
```

But in your case, it doesn't work because `push` returns a number (the length of the array plus the new item). There is no `splice` method for numbers.

```
myArray.push(...).splice(...)

// is equivalent to doing

const result1 = myArray.push(...)
const result2 = result1.splice(...) // But result1 isn't an array.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if the methods you want to chain all return an Array, `push` returns the length of the array:

```js
console.log([1,2].push(3)) // 3, not an array

console.log([1,2].map(x => x+1)) // [2,3], an array
```

Comment: be careful because `splice` returns an array of removed elements!